# MySql create view from 3 tables with latest id's

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried a couple of times with different methods, but didn't got it working like it should be:

-- Main table (m1)

```
+-----+-----------+
| Cid | location  |
+-----+-----------+
|  1  | Amsterdam |
|  2  | Berlin    |
|  3  | Paris     |
```

-- Info table 1 (i1)

```
+-----+-----+-------+------------------+
| id  | Cid | light |       date       |
+-----+-----+-------+------------------+
| 995 |   1 | off   | 10:30 22-09-2017 |
| 994 |   3 | on    | 10:30 22-09-2017 |
| 993 |   2 | off   | 10:30 22-09-2017 |
| 992 |   1 | on    | 09:20 22-09-2017 |
| 991 |   2 | on    | 09:20 22-09-2017 |
```

-- Info table 2 (i2)

```
+-----+-----+---------+
| id  | Cid |  task   |
+-----+-----+---------+
| 335 |   3 | measure |
| 334 |   2 | reboot  |
| 333 |   2 | standby |
| 332 |   1 | fixture |
| 331 |   2 | measure |
```

-- I want to have it outputted like this (which contains the latest ID's linked to Cid in the result):

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+------------------+---------+
| Cid & m1 id | location  | i1 light |     i1 date      | i2 task |
+-------------+-----------+----------+------------------+---------+
|           1 | Amsterdam | off      | 10:30 22-09-2017 | fixture |
|           2 | Berlin    | off      | 10:30 22-09-2017 | reboot  |
|           3 | Paris     | on       | 10:30 22-09-2017 | measure |
```

What I've tried is the following;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        `m1`.`id`,
        `m1`.`location`,
        `i1`.`light`,
        `i1`,`date`,
        `i2`.`task`,
    FROM
        ((`m1`
        JOIN `i1` ON ((`i1`.`Cid` = `m1`.`id`)))
        JOIN `i2` ON ((`i2`.`Cid` = `m1`.`id`)))
    WHERE
        `i1`.`id` IN (SELECT 
                MAX(`i1`.`id`)
            FROM
                `i1`
            GROUP BY `i1`.`Cid`)
    ORDER BY `m1`.`id`
```

Which results only the i1 with no doubles but does give more results of all because there are more i2 rows with that same Cid. I've tried left join as well, but didn't succeed.

Much appreciated!

Comment: hi, don't understand the logic of your output specifically i2 where 1(amsterdam) is a fixture not a measure.

Comment: Cid = 1 (Amsterdam) has two entries in Info table 1 (one with "off" and one with "on"). How do you choose which one you want to show?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn my fault, edited

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis, I would like to have the latest status, which is in this case in i1 off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there is probably a better way to do this, but this should work.

```
SELECT m1.id, 
       m1.location, 
       i1_max.light, 
       i1_max.date, 
       i2_max.task 
FROM   m1 
       JOIN (SELECT id, 
                    Cid, 
                    light, 
                    date 
             FROM   i1 
             WHERE  i1.Cid = m1.id 
             ORDER  BY date DESC 
             LIMIT  1) AS i1_max 
         ON m1.id = i1_max.Cid 
       JOIN (SELECT id, 
                    Cid, 
                    task 
             FROM   i2 
             WHERE  i2.Cid = m1.id 
             ORDER  BY id DESC 
             LIMIT  1) AS i2_max 
         ON m1.id = i2_max.Cid
```

Comment: still need to get the max for i2

Comment: Somehow I do get 'Error Code 1054. Unknown Column 'm1.Cid' in 'where clause'. Which seems right, because that needs to be 'm1.id'. Did you change this to Cid by purpose? Can't it combine by auto increment columns?

Comment: You are correct. References to m1.cid should be m1.id instead.  I got confused because your example m1 table in your question shows a Cid column and no id column. Let me update my answer

Comment: Somehow the `LIMIT 1` on `i1` and `i2` results just one result, for instance, just only on Amsterdam, not on Berlin and Paris. I had to `left join` as well, might that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

try this one.. it's a sql server format but should just work fine with mysql otherwise format accordingly.

```
select m.cid, m.location, i1.light,i1.Date,i2.task from 
m1 m
inner join
(
select b.cid,b.light,b.date from i1 b where b.id = 
  (select max(id) from i1 b1 where b1.cid = b.Cid)
 ) i1 on i1.Cid = m.cid
 inner join
(
select c.cid,c.task from i2 c where c.id = 
  (select max(id) from i2 c1 where c1.cid = c.Cid)
 ) i2 on i2.Cid = m.cid
```

Comment: @Kieftenbelt any luck with this?

Comment: thanks for this one! I've tried it, but somehow I do get errors in MySQLWorkbench. I do have to say that I've more weird errors that shouldn't be there so I keep you updated if this works!

Comment: you have to format this with mysql accordingly... i reckon max is different with mysql or something else.

Answer (score 0):

[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/MKR16775)

```
select m1.*, i1.light, l1.date, i2.task 
from m1 join 
(select max(id) id, cid from i1 group by cid) a on m1.cid = a.cid
join 
(select max(id) id, cid from i2 group by cid) b on m1.cid = b.cid
join i1 on a.id = i1.id
join i2 on b.id = i2.id
order by m1.cid
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: My answer is using T-SQL. I did not realize that the ask was for MySql database. MySql does not support window functions. Also, support for CTE is only available from MySql 8.0 onwards.

```
with i1latest (id, cid, light, [date], rown)
as 
(
    select id, cid, light, [date], row_number() over(partition by cid order by [date] desc) as rown
    from i1 
), i2latest (id, cid, task, rown)
as 
(
    select id, cid, task, row_number() over(partition by cid order by id desc) as rown
    from i2 
)
select m1.cid as cid, m1.location, i1n.light, i1n.[date], i2n.task  
from m1
join i1latest i1n
on m1.cid = i1n.cid
join i2latest i2n
on m1.cid = i2n.cid 
where i1n.rown = 1
and i2n.rown =1
```

Result:

```
cid location    light  date                     task
--- ----------- ------ ----------------------- ---------
1   Amsterdam   off    2017-03-20 17:23:34.733  fixture
2   Berlin      off    2017-03-20 17:23:34.733  reboot
3   Paris       on     2017-03-20 17:23:34.733  measure
```

Comment: My answer partitions the i1 table based on the date. Instead, it should be partitioned over the id column, if that is semantically more correct for your application's needs.

Comment: Thanks for this one. Never tried this way with the 'with' manner, but I don't get the `rown`, shouldn't that be `row_number()`? I do have already many errors with this in MySQLWorkbench, but seems like a legit way of doing it.

Comment: This is called [Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx). Are you getting the error in the Window function? I am using T-Sql. Looks like MySql might not support window functions.

Comment: I have updated the title of this question to indicate that this is related to mysql. :)